# Where Meteor Store the Meteorite Package

Tags: javascript, meteor

Where is the package that we downloaded by using meteorite stored at?

The reason is, I have setup two Ubuntu machines for development and when I want to develop on the other , I have to rerun the `mrt update`.

Before this on Windows machine I manually download the package, put it into a folder and run `meteor add ...` and never have to update anything if I move the source to other Windows machine.

Please explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Lubuntu, and for me the packages are stored in `~/.meteorite/packages` (and linked to from the folder `packages` in each project), but downloading them manually and putting them directly in the `packages` folder and adding them to the `smart.json` file should work.

However, re-running `mrt update` seems like a more convenient way than manually handling the packages. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Because I develop in 3 different machines, sometimes on Ubuntu, sometimes on Windows. I noticed that manually putting the package causes less problem on the development mobility but the update is PITA.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't use meteorite and the meteorite package manager doesn't gitignore your files. This can be convenient since an app can be dropped onto another windows pc and very nearly run.

Its a bit different with meteorite and ubuntu. When you add a package in, the other ubuntu instance has to downloaded these packages since the aliased folders are gitignored. Meteorite stores the packages in `~/.meteorite` and aliases them into `packages` in your app. So it wont transfer to the other ubuntu machine.

Meteor 0.9.0 addresses this issue. Not very long from now you can just develop your app like normal and you can expect it to run on another machine without any issues like this.

Comment: I cant wait for that! While putting the packages in the source/workspace really make it large, it is useful for people like me who develop on the run.